# Would you please help me to fix badblocks on my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, badblocks

I just ran this command:

```
sudo badblocks -svvn -c 262144 /dev/sda -force
```

And the result was:

```
Pass completed, 274 bad blocks found. (246/0/28 errors)
```

Would you please help me to know if these blocks are trimmed ot not, how to fix/trim them out, and what is these numbers refer to ? I'm totaly new to linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at `man badblocks`?

Answer (score 3):

As the man page says, don't run badblocks alone, instead use:

```
e2fsck -c /dev/sdxy
```

on the unmounted filesystem. This will automatically add the found bad blocks to the device's bad block list.

If you can't unmount the filesystenm in your running system, do it from a Live USB or DVD.